# Adding disks to Minio object server

Tags: minio

I have used the minio service binary (https://dl.minio.io/server/minio/release/linux-amd64/minio) and my /etc/default/minio options are as follows:

```
MINIO_VOLUMES="/sdc1/minio/"
MINIO_OPTS="-C /etc/minio --address localhost:9000"
```

Could someone tell me how can I modify the above options to add /sdb1/minio as an additional volume?

I tried adding the volume with semicolon and spaces to the first volume but neither worked. Semicolon was ignored while spaces would cause startup failure for the service.

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is by design.
No dynamic expansion.
https://github.com/minio/minio/issues/4364

Comment: But the design let's you have more volumes on each instance: https://docs.minio.io/docs/multi-tenant-minio-deployment-guide (Example 2)

Comment: Right.  But NOT after you start the cluster for the first time.

Comment: So, you can spin up 5 hosts with 5 disks each (for example). Each host knows about all of the others and all of the disks.

Once it initializes, you cannot add more hosts or disks.

Comment: I think you can still add hosts... the developers explain that adding hosts is the concept (similar to other cloud platforms)

Comment: @wmac, did you find a solution?